# Requesting completions from Pylance language server using request forwarding in VS Code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, pylance, python-language-server

Does Pylance provide completions for virtual documents? Should I be able to get completions from it using the `vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider` command?

I am making a VS Code extension that requires completions for Python code. I am following the [Embedded Programming Languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/embedded-languages) guide and experimenting with code from [LSP Example for Embedded Language using Request Forwarding](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/lsp-embedded-request-forwarding).

My modified version of the example code works when I have Pyright enabled (and Pylance disabled) in my VS Code Extension Development Host. I get the expected completions. But when I have Pylance enabled (and Pyright disabled) I do not get Python completions. In both cases I get completions when editing a normal Python file.

Why wouldn't I be getting completions from Pylance through my extension?

My language client creates a virtual document and executes the command:

```js
const clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
    documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: 'html1' }],
    middleware: {
        provideCompletionItem: async (document, position, context, token, next) => {
            const originalUri = document.uri.toString(true);
            virtualDocumentContents.set(originalUri, document.getText());

            const vdocUriString = `embedded-content://py/${encodeURIComponent(originalUri)}.py`;
            const vdocUri = Uri.parse(vdocUriString);
            return await commands.executeCommand<CompletionList>(
                'vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider',
                vdocUri,
                position,
                context.triggerCharacter
            );
        }
    }
};
```

And I have a content provider for the `embedded-content` protocol:

```js
workspace.registerTextDocumentContentProvider('embedded-content', {
    provideTextDocumentContent: uri => {
        const originalUri = uri.path.slice(1).slice(0, -3);
        const decodedUri = decodeURIComponent(originalUri);
        return virtualDocumentContents.get(decodedUri);
    }
});
```